# How to write boost::spirit::x3 rule?

Tags: c++, parsing, boost, boost-spirit

I'm a new comer of boost::spirit, I don't know how to write a set of rules, especially I don't know the meaning of template parameters of x3::rule. I have read the doc however I don't understand it.

I wonder if someone can write some examples.

P.S. I know that I should try by myself first and show my code, but I have tried for several times and have no ideas how to write it.

**Q1:**
From doc of spirit x3, we have:

> group       = '(' >> expression >> ')';
>
> factor      = integer | group;`
>
> term        = factor >> *(('*' >> factor) | ('/' >> factor));
>
> expression  = term >> *(('+' >> term) | ('-' >> term));

I wonder what is the type of `group`, `factor`, `term` and `expression`? (Of course x3::rule, but what is the type of them as a template?)

**Q2:** Once these rules are established, how can I use it?

**Q3:** How can I write a recursive rule?

......

Comment: I'd suggest to look at the samples. They explain it all